# Display sql tree Hierarchical data in ASP.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to build and display a hierarchical data structure in C#. Please see the image below of what I trying to achieve. I have two tables Sample and Sample Branch. SampleID is the relationship between the two tables. Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you running into issues?

Comment: There are a number of ways to perform a recursive query. Performance can vary, but a good starting point is to 1. used a stored procedure (allows you to modify the query if you need to improve performance; 2. start with a Common Table Expression (CTE) which allows a single query to be recursive.

Comment: Telling the true I don't know how to to do it. This what I got at the moment.   SELECT     Sample.SampleID,  SampleBranch.SampleBranchID
FROM         Sample INNER JOIN
                      SampleBranch ON Sample.SampleID = SampleBranch.SampleID